# Why is there no option to use SSLContext with GetTCP Processor in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

Why is there no option to use SSLContext with GetTCP Processor(Processor that connects to a TCP Server) in Apache Nifi? it is confusing that there is the option for ListenTCP(the Processor acts as a Server allow clients to connect), and "PutTcp"(used for sending data back to a Server) but not for GetTCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File a JIRA ticket so it gets prioritized https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI/issues/NIFI-10618?filter=addedrecently

"The GetTCP Processor does not seem to have received much attention since the original implementation. Supporting TLS through the SSL Context Service could be useful if you are interested in working on it. Taking a quick look at the code, however, implementing proper support for TLS looks like it would require significant refactoring of the design. GetTCP uses the Java NIO libraries, which is good in general, but makes it very difficult to support TLS. For this reason, adding support for TLS should also include refactoring the implementation approach to use Netty."